# How to pipe Windows "dir" in ANSI codepage

Tags: windows, command-line, ansi, dir

This applies to both Windows XP and Windows 7.

Some of my files have names with European characters, for example the German a-umlaut, also known as a-diaeresis.

These are displayed correctly in Windows Explorer, and also in a command shell (cmd.exe) window in response to the "dir" command.

However, if that "dir" command is directed to a file, e.g.

```
dir > file.txt
```

then the European characters in that file are represented in a DOS codepage; for example the a-umlaut is represented as decimal 132 (hex 0x84).  This is not what I want.  I want the file to be in the ANSI codepage, where for example a-umlaut is decimal 228 (hex 0xE4).

Issuing the command "cmd /?" results in help information including the line

```
/A      Causes the output of internal commands to a pipe or file to be ANSI
```

This sounds like exactly what I want.  However, either the sequence of commands

```
cmd /A
dir > file.txt
exit
```

or the equivalent single command line

```
cmd /A /C dir > file.txt
```

produces exactly the same file.txt as before; with its Europoean characters still in the DOS code page.

So my question is, how can I get "dir" to write a file in the ANSI codepage?

- Rich

Comment: Have you tried with the Unicode (`/U`) flag instead of ANSI?

Comment: Switching from OEM to ANSI is like upgrading from DOS to Windows 3.1... it will cause even more suffering in the end. Use Unicode if possible.

Comment: Nice plug for Unicode, but for many reasons this has to interface with existing scripts that use single-byte characters.

Answer (score 3):

I think there is easy way, "from the box"

```
chcp 1252
dir > file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You are being led up the garden path by the letter "A".  The `/A` option isn't distinguishing "ANSI" from "OEM" code pages.  It's distinguishing 8-bit single-byte/multiple-byte character sets from 16-bit Unicode (the `/U` option).   [8-bit SBCS/MBCS output from a Win32 program, such as `CMD`, to a console is handled in the "OEM" code page.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20051027-37/?p=33593)

Comment: OK, JdeBP, I understand what you're saying: the help information sure is misleading.  But then how do I get the output of the "DIR" command to be in ANSI code page (well, ISO 8859-1, the standard for Windows) rather than the OEM DOS codepage (850 in my case)?  I suppose I could write a simple EXE filter with a lookup table, and then pipe my DIR through it, or maybe I could write a whole new replacement for DIR which does what I want in the first place.  But surely there's an easier way!

Comment: I found one way to do it: download my utility [cp850win](http://www.richpasco.org/utilities/cp850win.html)
and then issue the command

`dir | cp850win > file.txt`